# Can the inverse function theorem be extended to regions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The inverse function theorem states that:

If the determinant of the Jacobian of a function $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is non-zero at a point $\vec{x}_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then there exists an inverse function $F^{-1}$ in a neighborhood of $\vec{x}_0$ such that $F^{-1}(F(\vec x)) = \vec x$.

Can the theorem be extended to regions in some way? For example, suppose that the Jacobian of $F$ is non-zero in an open set $\Omega \subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Does it follow that $F$ has an inverse in all of $\Omega$?

Comment: What is true is that if the Jacobian is zero at $x_0$ then $F$ is invertible in some neighborhood of $x_0$. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem), for example.

Comment: @rogerl The Jacobian determinant has to be *non-zero* for the inverse to exist.

Comment: Ack. Of course I meant to write "if the Jacobian is *non*zero"

Comment: @rogerl What is the difference between your statement and what I wrote?

Comment: You are trying to take a local result for a big set into a global result for a smaller set. Why would you think this could be done?

Comment: Because you can start with a neighborhood guaranteed by the theorem around $x_0$, then apply the theorem to another point $x_1$ within this neighborhood, and construct an inverse within a neighborhood of $x_1$. Obviously the inverses must be the same in both neighborhoods. You can continue like this, with an endless sequence of points $x_0, x_1, \dots$. My intuition is that in some cases, such a construction can cover a domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
$$
f(x)=x^2
$$
On the open set $(-1,0)\cup (0,1)=\Omega$. The Jacobian is nonvanishing but we still do not have injectivity on $\Omega$.

Comment: What about a connected domain? I am trying to figure out the conditions I need to add to the theorem to extend it to a region.

Answer (score 0):

No in the case $n>1:$ That's because every ball $B(a,r)\subset \mathbb R^n$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ itself. You seem to be aware that if $n>1,$ that there exists $F:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ with $\det F(x) \ne 0$ everywhere, but such that $F$ is not injective. Composing with the above diffeomorphism yields a counterexample for $B(a,r).$

Comment: Can you construct an explicit example?